Why do we need this additional check in this concurrent queue implementation?
Working through a textbook which suggests the following implementation for a concurrent queue. I am wondering why the two if statements, which are highlighted in the code, are necessary. After the snippet I include some reasoning about why I don't think they are necessary, but I'm still hesitant to go against the word of my textbook, so I would love some explanation about why we need these.
Please feel free to ignore my "proof" of why we don't need the if statements: just trying to give some insight into how I'm thinking about the problem.
The implementation:
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    Node(T val, Node* next = nullptr)
    : value(val), next(next)
    {}
    T value;
    std::atomic<Node*> next;
};

template<typename T>
struct UnboundedQueue
{
    std::atomic<Node*> head;
    std::atomic<Node*> tail;
    void enq(T val);
    T deq(void);
};

template<typename T>
void UnboundedQueue::enq(T val)
{
    Node* node = new Node(val);

    while(true)
    {
        Node* last = tail.load();
        Node* next = last->next.load();

// ********* THIS if statement
        if(last == tail.load())
        {
            if(next == nullptr)
            {
                if(last->next.compare_exchange_weak(next, node))
                {
                    tail.compare_exchange_weak(last, node);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tail.compare_exchange_weak(last, next);
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::optional<T> UnboundedQueue::deq(void)
{
    while(true)
    {
        Node* first = head.load();
        Node* last = tail.load();
        Node* next = first->next.load();
// ********* and THIS if statement
        if(first == head.load())
        {
            if(last == first)
            {
                if(first->next == nullptr)
                {
                    return std::nullopt;
                }
                else
                {
                    tail.compare_exchange_weak(last, next);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(head.compare_exchange_weak(first, next))
                {
                    T res = first->value;            
                    // this is UB but question isn't about that
                    delete first;
                    return res;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Intuitively, these checks feel unnecessary.
Firstly, we note that we have the following two invariants:

The head node never moves past the tail node.

Informal Proof: To have this be the case we would need that head == tail and that head == first (to execute the CAS). But as we load last after loading first, this would mean that last == tail, and so we would enter the first if statement and not move head past tail.

If a node was ever the tail node and its next value is nullptr, then it is currently the tail node.

Informal Proof: We never set the next value of a node to nullptr. So for a node to lose its status as the tail we would first need to add another node after it, setting its next value to not nullptr.
And so now we assume that we remove the if statements and enter each of the methods with the following conditions being true, showing that in each case, nothing incorrect happens to our state:
Assume that last != tail.load()

Case 1: next == nullptr and by our second invariant we have that our assumption must be false.


Case 2: next != nullptr. Then we perform tail.compare_exchange_weak(last, next), which will do nothing because tail != last

Now assume that first != head.load()

Case 1: last == first
>>Case 1.1: first->next == nullptr.
So last == first, and therefore first was once equal to tail. And therefore by our second invariant we have that first == tail and so, by our second invariant, as our head never moves past tail, we must have that first == head and so our assumption is false.
>>Case 1.2: first->next != nullptr
>>>Case 1.2.1: first != tail: and so tail.compare_exchange_weak(last, next) does nothing.
>>>Case 1.2.2: first == tail: and therefore first == head, as the head can only move forward, but cannot move forward past the tail by our first invariant.


Case 2: last != first:
And we will perform head.compare_exchange_weak(first, next), which will do nothing because head != first (by assumption)

I'll note that I don't have a ton of experience with concurrency, so certainly could have made a mistake somewhere.

If this is concurrent code, someone else can have changed head after it was first loaded. If so, the if will fail and we have to start over.

@BoP So is it just a rule of thumb in concurrent code that we do these sort of checks? Or is there an explicit reason why we do this check in this situation.
